# How to detect (or log) if MSBuild is skipping a project because it is up-to-date?

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

In Visual Studio, you get a report after every build listing the projects it skipped because they were up-to-date. You might get something like this.

========== Build: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 59 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Using MSBuild though (command line), I can't seem to do that. The best I can do is parse the log file for individually skipped targets (which would be pretty annoying to do) but even then I don't know if the project was skipped. If Visual Studio does it I'm assuming it is doable. I just can't figure out how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to BUILD and to RE-BUILD. RE-BUILD will do what you need.

The basic command syntax is

```
msdev FileName [/MAKE "ProjectName – ConfigName | ALL"] [/REBUILD /CLEAN /NORECURSE /OUT LogFile /USEENV]
```

where FileName is the name of your project (.dsp) or workspace (.dsw) file.
For example, the following syntax deletes all intermediate files and then builds a project called MyProject:

```
msdev MyProject.dsp /MAKE "MyProject – Win32 Debug" /REBUILD
```

source : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

FOR LOGGING :

1. Enable Build timing in Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Project Settings > Build Timing It actually starts msbuild with PerformanceSummary flag
2. If you are interested in elapsed time of the whole build
   2.1Change Tools > Options > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity at least to Normal. (in this case it is logged just to output window)

I you wish to have it stored into build log file change also Change Tools > Options > Build and Run > MSBuild project build log file verbosity at least to Normal.
Build of each vcxproj file is logged into file specified in Project > Properties >Configuration Properties >Build Log File

If you don’t see any time after hitting the build command, it can be because your project is up to date (nothing was changed) – detected by the incremental build feature of the msbuild.

Comment: This seems like its all for C++ probjects and solutions. I'm using C# and .sln files as well as csproj files.